# Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED - PLSQL Error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I simply want to prevent users from running UPDATE statement without WHERE clause. I provided my PLSQL below

```
create or replace PROCEDURE secure_update(update_query IN varchar2)
IS
  msg varchar2(30000);
  flag char(1);
  qry varchar2(30000);
BEGIN

  IF upper(update_query) LIKE 'UPDATE%SET%WHERE%=%' THEN
    flag := '1';
  ELSE
    flag := '0';
  END IF;

  IF (flag = '1') THEN
    --qry := update_query;
    execute immediate update_query into msg;
  END IF;

  dbms_output.put_line(msg);

END;
```

That's how I execute it

```
EXEC secure_update
('
UPDATE dummy_table
SET col1 = ''whatever''
WHERE pk = ''1234''
')
```

I keep getting this message:

> Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED

**Can you please help me find out how to overcome this error?**

Comment: when using `dynamic sql`, try to put the varchar values inside two two quotes `''whatever''` I mean use `''` for `'`

Comment: Aside from the error you're seeing, the unbalanced single quotes, and that `exec` has to be on one line, I'm not sure about your goal. If you want to check for a `where` clause so the caller can't update all records at once, what is stopping them doing something like `where 1=1`?

Comment: This plsql is for experimentation purposes. I'm not considering security at this point

Comment: Unrelated but: why not use a real `boolean` for the `flag` variable?

Comment: @AlexPoole: the exec being required on a single line is a limitation of SQL*Plus. Not all SQL clients have the same limitation.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - SQL Developer does though. but since you've removed the tag, moot point *8-) Although that does actually seem to be the problem leading to this specific error, preceded with PLS-00306 which the OP didn't show.

Comment: @AlexPoole: I removed the tag because I thought that due to the incorrect `into` clause this is not caused by the actual SQL client being used - but if you think this **is** related to the wrong `exec` and the SQL client then feel free to re-add the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, please see the changes, dont use the into clause in execute immediate

```
create or replace PROCEDURE secure_update(update_query IN varchar2)
IS
  msg varchar2(30000);
  flag char(1);
  qry varchar2(30000);
BEGIN

  IF upper(update_query) LIKE 'UPDATE%SET%WHERE%=%' THEN
    flag := '1';
    dbms_output.put_line('updated succesfully');
  ELSE
    flag := '0';
    dbms_output.put_line('no where clause in update');
  END IF;

  IF (flag = '1') THEN
    --qry := update_query;
    execute immediate update_query ;
  END IF;

  END;
```

if you want to use varchar in update then please see this

```
SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select * from test2;

A     B
----- -----
a     b

code to execute procedure :

declare
lsql varchar2(100):= 'update test2 set a=''z'' where b=''b'' ';
begin
secure_update(lsql);
end;

output:     updated succesfully

SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select * from test2;

A     B
----- -----
z     b

declare
lsql varchar2(100):= 'update test2 set a=''z''';
begin
secure_update(lsql);
end;

output

no where clause in update
```

another example

```
SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select * from test1;

      VAL1       VAL2       VAL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          2          4
         3          2          4
       123          2          3
        42          3

SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> exec secure_update('update test1 set val1=555 where val1=2');
updated succesfully

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> select * from test1;

      VAL1       VAL2       VAL3
---------- ---------- ----------
       555          2          4
         3          2          4
       123          2          3
        42          3


SCOTT@research 16-APR-15> exec secure_update('update test1 set val1=555');
no where clause in update

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer (and SQL*Plus, but possibly not other clients!) needs the `exec` command to be on a single line. You didn't show the earlier errors you would have got from that invocation:

```
EXEC secure_update
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SECURE_UPDATE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Error starting at line : 25 in command -
('
UPDATE dummy_table
SET col1 = ''whatever''
WHERE pk = ''1234''
')
Error at Command Line : 25 Column : 2
Error report -
SQL Error: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
```

The procedure is being called with no arguments, because there are none on the same line as the actual `exec`, so you get a PLS-00306 from that line. Then the remainder is interpreted as a separate command, which gets the 'invalid SQL type' error you reported. (In SQL Developer, that is; in SQL*Plus you'd get the same PLS-00306 for the first part, but `ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword` for the rest).

You can either move the whole statement into one line:

```
EXEC secure_update ('UPDATE dummy_table SET col1 = ''whatever'' WHERE pk = ''1234''');
```

Or use an explicit anonymous block rather than the `exec` shorthand:

```
BEGIN
  secure_update
  ('UPDATE dummy_table
  SET col1 = ''whatever''
  WHERE pk = ''1234''
  ');
  dbms_output.put_line('after');
END;
/
```

Note also that I've had to move the `UPDATE` up a line anyway, as your check doesn't allow for any whitespace (including a line break) at the start of the command. The `into msg` in your procedure isn't doing anything but doesn't seem to be causing a problem; if you want to see how many rows were updated use SQL%ROWCOUNT after the `execute immediate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

An `UPDATE` statement should not be executed `into` anything, it should just be executed.  This code demonstrates the error, although the error message is slightly different than the one you posted.

```
create table dummy_table(col1 varchar2(100), pk number);

declare
    msg varchar2(30000);
begin
    execute immediate q'[
        UPDATE dummy_table
        SET col1 = 'whatever'
        WHERE pk = '1234'
    ]' into msg;
end;
/

ORA-01007: variable not in select list
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Remove the `into msg` and it will work.  Also, the alternative quoting mechanism is used to avoid escaping quotation marks.

Comment: By the way, are you trying to build a generic program to handle any type of dynamic SQL statement?  If so, you may be in for a lot of work.  Just figuring out what kind of statement it is and getting an appropriate feedback message is complicated.  I'm working on such a system [here](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer).  It won't be ready for a few weeks, but it may give you an idea of how difficult the task can be.